# Closing SQL connections (NHibernate)

Tags: sql, nhibernate, connection

I have a test console app that is executing sql scripts to create a database and its tables, then inserting data. I use DAO to create, retrieve, update, and delete from the tables and then try and drop the database, but it can't because it says it is currently in use. How do I kill the connection? Through debugging and running a sql script to see the total connections, I've narrowed it down to this piece of code that is not killing the connection. Even though it says the connections are cleared, the database says it is still connected.

```
foreach (ISessionFactory factory in this.connections.Values)
{
    factory.Close();
}

this.connections.Clear();
this.connections = null;
```

Comment: Normally, you don't have to close the sessionfactory. Why do you have multiple sessionfactories? There might be an open connection somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate manages all the database connections itself. It opens and closes the database as it sees fit, but you can try to call Session.Disconnect to get it to disconnect from the ADO.NET connection.

However ... if you have Connection Pooling enabled, which is normally the 'default' connection behavior, the connection will only be returned to the connection pool, not released, and it will still show as a connection, so you would have to clear the connection pool.

Unfortunately, I do not know if you can do this directly thru NHibernate, but you can use a SQLConnection object to issue a ClearPool or ClearAllPools call ...

Comment: Thanks! I was originally clearing the pools in the code and it wasn't working so I tried using Pooling=false in the connection string and it seems to do the trick. Why it works in the connection string and not in the code beats me.

Comment: The connection pool is a GOOD thing. Connections in the pool DON'T keep any transactions open or consume any resources so you DON'T need to "clean" it. On the other hand, you also don't have to create a new connection when a connection is available in the pool. "Cleaning" the pool will definitely hurt performance